# ros-canopen publishing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the documentation for canopen_chain_node, in the node configuration, it allows you to set ros publishers for certain objects for debugging purposes. This uses SDO's and therefore blocks the control loop.

My question is: If my EDS files specify PDO's, does ros-canopen automatically publish the PDO's into the ROS system when the package is up and running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273550/ros-canopen-publishing/) by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you map objects, `ros_canopen` will read data from PDOs and not via SDOs.
There is no option to publish all mapped  data automatically.

Please note that you need an exclamation mark behind the object index to read mapped data periodically.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2017-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0